# Remove more then one HeatmapLayer from Google Maps with one click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a button which adds a heatmaplayer to my map. When pressing it twice. There are 2 heatmaplayers stacked. When pressing the delete heatmaplayer button only 1 heatmaplayer get's deleted. Why is that so? How can i delete all stacked heatmaps with one click?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Heatmaps</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <button onclick="createHeatmap()">Create Heatmap</button>
      <button onclick="deleteHeatmap()">Delete Heatmap</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map" style="height: 600px; width: 800px;"></div>
    <script>
var map, heatmap;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {lat: 37.775, lng: -122.434},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  });
}
function createHeatmap(){
        var heatmapdata = [
                       new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
                       new google.maps.LatLng(37.782745, -122.444586),
                       new google.maps.LatLng(37.782842, -122.443688),];
        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data: heatmapdata,
        });
        heatmap.setMap(map);
}

function deleteHeatmap(){
    heatmap.setMap(null);
}
    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep track of all the "layers" that you create, and then no matter how much heatmap you add, you just erase them with a for loop (looping through an array of created heatmaps).

This is the main function which nullifies the heatmaps and empties the array so when you start all over the array also starts from zero-index:

```
    function deleteHeatmap(){
       for (var k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
                     array[k].setMap(null);
         }
       array=[];
    }
```

Here is the example in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/3q6etox0/3/

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Heatmaps</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <button onclick="createHeatmap()">Create Heatmap</button>
      <button onclick="deleteHeatmap()">Delete Heatmap</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map" style="height: 600px; width: 800px;"></div>
    <script>
var map, heatmap;
        var heatmapdata;
var array=[];
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {lat: 37.775, lng: -122.434},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  });
}
function createHeatmap(){
        heatmapdata = [
                       new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
                       new google.maps.LatLng(37.782745, -122.444586),
                       new google.maps.LatLng(37.782842, -122.443688),];
        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data: heatmapdata,
        });
        array.push(heatmap);
        heatmap.setMap(map);
}

function deleteHeatmap(){

         for (var k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
                 array[k].setMap(null);

    }
         array=[];
}
    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very nice thanks. Since i want to create stacked heatmaps that's the solution i need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either delete (remove from the map) any existing heatmap before you create a new one (losing access to the original) or only allow a single heapmap to be created.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68kxruhq/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map, heatmap;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {
      lat: 37.775,
      lng: -122.434
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  });
}

function createHeatmap() {
  if (!heatmap || !heatmap.getMap || heatmap.getMap() == null) {
    var heatmapdata = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782745, -122.444586),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782842, -122.443688),
    ];
    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: heatmapdata,
    });
    heatmap.setMap(map);
  }
}

function deleteHeatmap() {
  heatmap.setMap(null);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization"></script>
<div id="floating-panel">
  <button onclick="createHeatmap()">Create Heatmap</button>
  <button onclick="deleteHeatmap()">Delete Heatmap</button>
</div>
<div id="map" style="height: 600px; width: 800px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, also very useful solution but I want to create stacked heatmaps so the other solutions fits a bit more to my specific use case.